# Retrieving data from Disk Utility Image

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, disk-image, dmg-image

I created an image of my mac using disk utility.  It's a `.dmg`.  It has a lot of data on it (about 1 TB) and I only want one file from it.  Is there any way I can selectively pull information from it, besides reimaging a computer and then copying 1 file?

I'm comfortable with the command line

EDIT: Grammar

Comment: Double-clicking should mount the image. Do you experience any issues with that?

Comment: Well, that was easy.  :)